# Instantiating an object on the Heap

Tags: c++, object, compiler-errors, heap-memory

I receive the error:

```
hashing.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
hashing.cpp:96: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Linked_HashTable’
hashing.cpp:96: error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘LinkedList_HashTable*’ in initialization
hashing.cpp:96: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘Linked_HashTable’
```

When compiling I my code.  I think I am missing something pretty easy to figure out.

The code that is giving me the error is:

```
Array_HashTable *linear_div_hash = new Array_HashTable(sizeDiv);
LinkedList_HashTable *chain_div_hash = new Linked_HashTable(sizeDiv);
Array_HashTable *doubleHash = new Array_HashTable(sizeDiv);
```

Where the constructor for both `Array_HashTable` and `LinkedList_HashTable()` takes an integer like `sizeDiv` is.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Accepting answers is to StackOverflow what flowers and chocolates are to first dates. Consider going back to your old questions and accepting answers for them; it may prove to make people more likely to help you with this and future questions!

Comment: You should use a smart pointer to hold these resources.

Comment: @corsiKa You bring flowers and chocolate to the *first* date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should

```
LinkedList_HashTable *chain_div_hash = new Linked_HashTable(sizeDiv);
```

be

```
LinkedList_HashTable *chain_div_hash = new LinkedList_HashTable(sizeDiv);
```

? (Note the missing `List` in your code).

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedList_HashTable *chain_div_hash = new LinkedList_HashTable(sizeDiv);
```

Maybe you typed `Linked_HashTable` but ment `LinkedList_HashTable`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mistyped `LinkedList_HashTable` as `Linked_HashTable` on the line `LinkedList_HashTable *chain_div_hash = new Linked_HashTable(sizeDiv);` causing the compiler to think `Linked_HashTable(sizeDiv);` is a function call to an implicitly declared function that returns an `int`.